# Best way to create row and columns in tab-pane

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having trouble with creating my form which is placed in a tab-pane. It seems that my labels and input 
elements are crossing each others bounderies when labels are to long or the window made smaller

My code can be seen here .. please notice that labels and inputs dont stay aligned when window size changes. It seems like making rows and columns inside tab-pane is not working the same way as when they are created outside that class.

http://www.bootply.com/I3Iwdr4UVj

It's as if the input element does not know the boundry of the label ..

Are there other ways to nicely create the form inside my tab-pane ? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to give a className with wider width, .col-sm-2 is too narrow for a label:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" id="pwd" class="form-control">
          </div>
</div>
```

I would suggest you always try to get the sum of 12 when you use Bootstrap classes.